# i[Pod|Phone|Pad|*] backups in iTunes

Tags: iphone, backup, itunes

iTunes <-> iPhone. At sync time, a back-up is performed. Which data is included, which data is not? i.e. are songs (potentially redundant) backed-up so that a computer ends up having both the source file on the filesystem and the copy within the device back-up? Is anything on the iPhone filesystem *not* backed up? (i.e. on a Mac using Time Machine, some files are excluded from the back-up even if not all of them can be recreated upon restore - I lost my postfix config this way..)

Comment: a note to people voting to close: syncing a device with a computer is explicitly ontopic on Super User.  this may be a duplicate, however.

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty confident that songs are not backed up, as the last time I did a restore I had to reload all of the songs to my iPhone. It seemed to backup all config files for the phone, and messages, phone numbers, etc. Anything that can be downloaded and synced again from itunes was skipped.

I may be wrong here, but thats what I remember from experience.

Comment: I'd second this, it's anything that can't be resync'd, which means you're out of luck if the songs/whatever get deleted from your computer and then you plug in your phone and it syncs and deletes them from the phone.

Comment: There are programs to get around that though. Ive personally never lost music off my iPhone during a restore, as I will back it up before doing it.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answers guys! A detailed answer as to: what exactly gets backed up and what not is still missing though (I mean: even on the 'net at large right now) or is there a link to answer this somewhere public, actually?